# Xib based view is always full-screen and displayed on top of all other views

Tags: ios, xib

This is a generic question and I must be missing something simple.

I've create a xib file, put a few views in it, created a view class inherited from UI view, defined initWithCoder and initWithFrame, set File's Owner of the xib to this class. The view class loads the xib via `loadNibNamed`. I add this custom view to storyboard to a view which takes half of the screen. The view appears correct on the storyboard, I can set constraints for it, but when the app runs, the view is actually taking a full screen. It is not appearing inside the view I've added it to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have constrains set for the xib you are adding ? or the view that contains it ?

Comment: yes, constraints in xib are all relevant to superview, for example, Toolbar.Leading Equal Superview.Leading. There is a couple of 'absolute' constraints for height of some views.